# Why does adding a border on my picture will decrease it's size?

Tags: html, css, less

Are there any ways to add a border onto a image without decreasing the size of the image?

```
<li class="profile-active">

<a href="profile">

<img src="http://placepic.me/profiles/80-80" width="40" height="40" class="img-circle"></a>

</li>

<style>
.profile-acive{
  border: 10px solid #5693F9;
}
</style>
```

This is the CSS of the circle

```
// Perfect circle
.img-circle {

  border-radius: 50%; // set radius in percents

}
```

Comment: Watch out, there is a typo in your css class.

Comment: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h3domt73/) use border for image `inset`

Comment: set `box-sizing:content-box;` (which is actually the default value) on your list item `li`. Somewhere else in your code you must have changed the default value for box-sizing to `border-box`

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes: `inset` is just the style of the border and does not work as `inset` in `box-shadow`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should set both the `border` and `border-radius` on the img element

```
.img-circle {
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 10px solid #5693F9; 
}
```

This by default should work fine, and the border will not cause the picture to descrease in size

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vn7121mj/1/)**

That being said, if somewhere in your code you have changed the default value for box-sizing to be border-box,

Like so:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vn7121mj/2/)**

...then you'll have to manually override it here on your image with `box-sizing:content-box;` to make sure that the border will not cause the picture to descrease in size. Like so:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vn7121mj/3/)**

### NB:

If you want a rounded border do not use `outline`

The outline property doesn't support rounded borders -

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vn7121mj/5/)**

Answer (score 3):

You can use `outline` CSS property instead as this does not take up any space.

Answer (score 1):

*Need to see more code that can affect the `<img>` and `<li>` tag.*

But **I'm pretty sure it's because you set somewhere (or you use a framework - such as Bootstrap - or a reset CSS that set)** :

```
li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

And :

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Check the relevant CSS on the img tag and on the li tag. **If border-box model is set** :

- border size is included in total width
- so img (max-width: 100%) is 20px smaller (as border size is 10px)

Answer (score 0):

It's not because you added a border. It's because you gave attributes width and height as 40.
Try changing it into 400 or any preferred value and your image will have preferred size. Adding a border doesn't decrease image size.

Answer (score 0):

use this into you img class="img-circle img-border".

.img-border{border:0.5px solid;}

if not works border:0.5px solid; add this into your img-circle stylesheet

good luck!